# EXCEL - Error while opening excel workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, xlsx, vba

I have Office 2007. 
Each time I launch Excel, or open an existing file, it tries to access some old file and I get the following error pop up:

'E:\xyz.txt' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. 
If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

Please help on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check all add-ins in Excel option. Possibly there is one which starts with your Excel and it could keep some references to external sources like 'xyz.txt' file.

Comment: Thanks so much. it was an old add-in, which was active. I removed that and now its working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have an old add-in still active?
Developer > Add-Ins

if you see any custom add-ins, deactivate them and see if the problem remains.

Alternatively you could check in the VBA window what xla / xlam files are active and see if the file you mention is hiding somewhere in the code thereof

Comment: Thanks so much K_B. Yes it was an old add-in, which was active. I removed that and now its working perfectly.